# Aplicação extremamente lenta após implementar a lib Dozer

Tags: java

Tenho uma aplicação JSF.

Acabei de incluir uma camada de DTOs e preciso transferir os valores das Entidades para os DTOs e vice-e-versa.

Procurando no Google, encontrei recomendações da lib [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) no SOen.

Incluí a dependência e a utilizei como *Singleton*, conforme especificado pela documentação.

Tanto as entidades quanto os DTOs possuem os mesmos nomes de campos, dessa forma não é necessário fazer mapeamento explícito (XML ou anotações).

Com tudo, a aplicação fixou **extremamente** lenta após incluir a dependência do Dozer.

Até habilitei o log da lib para ver o que acontecia e está tudo ok. Não vou postar o log aqui porquê ele é enorme, mas já li ele inteiro várias vezes e está tudo certo.

---

Estou usando o Hibernate com a maioria dos relacionamentos com `FetchType.LAZY`. Incluí o arquivo de configuração `dozer.properties` com a configuração abaixo e o comportamento continua o mesmo.

```
dozer.beans.proxy-resolver-bean=org.dozer.util.HibernateProxyResolver
```

---

Segue o código da classe utilitária que criei para copiar os valores:

```
import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.dozer.Mapper;

public final class CopyPropertiesUtil {

    private static Mapper mapper = getInstance();

    public static final Object copyProperties(final Object origin, final Class<?> destinationType) {
        return origin == null ? null : mapper.map(origin, destinationType);
    }

    private static final Mapper getInstance() {
        return mapper == null ? new DozerBeanMapper() : mapper;
    }
}
```

Qualquer ajuda ou sugestão é bem-vinda.

Comment: *Até habilitei o log da lib para ver o que acontecia e está tudo ok. Não vou postar o log aqui porquê ele é enorme, mas já li ele inteiro várias vezes e está tudo certo.* - Será que o log não é o gargalo?

Comment: Habilitei o log justamente pq estava lento @VictorStafusa Todavia, vou desabilitar amanhã e comento o comportamento